# How can I make an asymmetric correlation in r?

Tags: r, correlation

Sometimes I used to use `psych::corr.test` function with two data frames like:

```
df1 <- tibble(a=c(1,2,4,5,67,21,21,65,1,5), b=c(21,5,2,6,8,4,2,6,2,2))

df2 <- tibble(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8), b=c(1,6,54,8,3,8,9,5,2,1), c=c(1,4,6,8,5,3,9,7,5,4))

corr <- corr.test(df1,df2, adjust = "BH")
```

And I was getting p-values from `corr$p.adj`
But sometimes it gives me strange repetitive p.values like:

```
          a         b         c
a 0.5727443 0.5964993 0.5727443
b 0.2566757 0.5727443 0.2566757
```

Does anyone know how adequate these p-values are? Can we do this with the `corr.test`? If not, how can I make an asymmetric correlation?

I'm stressed that if I try to perform symmetric correlation like

```
df <- bind_cols(df1,df2[-3])
corr <- corr.test(df, adjust = "BH")
```

it's p-values not so repetative:

```
Probability values (Entries above the diagonal are adjusted for multiple tests.) 
      a...1 b...2 a...3 b...4
a...1  0.00  0.97  0.62  0.72
b...2  0.97  0.00  0.38  0.62
a...3  0.39  0.06  0.00  0.62
b...4  0.60  0.40  0.41  0.00
```

UPD: Okay, I realised that it's as repetitive as the first and I'm a bit stupid.

Comment: The "repetitive result" you obtain is probably due to the small size of your samples. Try to use a bigger sample size and check the p-values

Comment: @R18 Thought about it, thank you. It seems that on larger samples it workd more correctly. But I'm stressed that if I perform symmetric correlation like in the example I added to the question, p-values not so repetative

Comment: Okay, I realised that it's as repetitive as the first and I'm a bit stupid. Thank you!

Comment: note that corr.test calculates a pearson correlation, which is symmetric. i.e. corr(a,b) == corr(b,a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BH correction is based on computing the cumulative minimum of `n/i * p`, where the `p` has your `n = 6` unadjusted p-values in decreasing order, and `i` is `6:1`.  (You can see the calculation in `psych::p.adjust`.)

Because it's a cumulative minimum (i.e. the first value, then the min of the first and second, then the min of the first to third, etc.) there are likely to be repetitions.